# How to join full name with shortcut

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables, first with full names of countries (only one column):

```
Poland 
Germany 
Czech Republic
```

and second table with shortcuts of those names

```
PL
DE
CZ
```

How to join those two tables to one with two columns: country and country shortcut?

```
Poland PL
Germany DE ect
```

Comment: You really can't do that unless you have a column in common. Really, it seems like what you want as the result set is what you'd need in one of the tables to be able to do this. Joins are generally applied when the tables have multiple columns and you're trying to return a data set that has some columns from table A and some columns from table B.

Comment: You should store that data in one table. One column for the full names, and one column for the shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

If the first table is named country, the second table is called abbr and the third table called table3 to find the abbrivation from the name it would look like this.

```
SELECT *
FROM country AS c
JOIN table3 as t3 on c.country = T3.country
JOIN abbr AS a on a.abbrivation = T3.abbrivation
```

Comment: Ok but how to match exact country with abbr? This is the problem.

Comment: I dnn't understand @matjan2  you have the contry in one table and want to get the abbr?